# Using If-else statements to calculate if employee is late or in time

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a n if-else statement inside a select statement to calculate
if an employee is in time or late however I keep messing it up.

If the employee clock in time is <= 8:00 then in a specified column says "InTime"
with a green flag else "Late" with a red flag.
 Any Tips.

SELECT TimeMasterID,CardNo,FName,LName,LocIn,DeviceIn,DateTimeOut,LocOut,DeviceOut,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateTimeIn,108)AS DateTimeIn,

```
    CASE
    WHEN DateTimeIn <= '08:00:00' THEN 'INTIME'
    ELSE 'LATE'

END AS Punctuality
FROM TIMEMASTER;
```

Comment: Please post you SQL code, then people may help.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of Case statement something like this

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT CASE WHEN  CAST(@d AS TIME) <= '08:00:00.000' THEN 'In Time'
            ELSE 'Late' END
```

dont know what exactly you are doing with this information, but if you want to use IF..ELSE you could do something like

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();         

IF (CAST(@d AS TIME) <= '08:00:00.000')
     BEGIN
       PRINT 'In Time'
     END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN 
      PRINT 'Lazy Git or Late Commer'
     END
```